# How to wait for AWS Cloudsearch to index documents?

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I'm uploading data to cloudsearch by posting documents as a batch. If I execute a search immediately afterward, sometimes the documents have been indexed and can be found and at other times they'll be available a few seconds later. Is there a way to poll or wait for the documents to be committed to the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to be notified that documents have been indexed, unfortunately.  You can poll the domain to see if a given document has been added or deleted.  Polling to see if a document has been updated is not so straightforward a task, but can still be done, if you know what's been changed.  Either way, there's no elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Right, sadly this is what I now do.